# SSIS - Dynamically moving Files to Folder with Matching Substring Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm using a foreach loop and file system task to move files into specific folders (or trying to at least).

i.e.

A file name can be 100000 and it needs to go to folder 1000
File 102000 needs to go to folder 1020
File 103000 need to go to folder 1030
etc
etc

I'm struggling with how to move the files to the correct folder.

I thought I could use a variable with the upper level directory followed by a substring of the filename variable held in the foreach loop

e.g.

```
"D:\\Archive\\" + SUBSTRING(@[USER::Variable],1,4)
```

But that doesn't work and I get an error that the path format is not supported.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: before asking your first question is it better to read the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more on asking question and other helpful informations, also to get your first `informed` badge

Comment: Try casting your variable to a string: `SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR, 6) @[USER::Variable,1,4)`

Comment: Are you moving file using a `File System Task` or `Script Task` or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your issue

First of all,I think the error is because the variable contains the fullpath not only the filename so you have to use a similar expression:

```
"D:\\Archive\\" + LEFT(RIGHT( @[User::Variable] , FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::Variable] ) , "\\", 1) - 1),4)
```

### Detailed Solutions

**First Method - Using script Task**

Try using a script task to achieve this, Just select your variable as a `ReadOnlyVariable` in the Script Task. and use a similar script *(I Used Vb.net)*

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim strFile As String = Dts.Variables.Item("User::Variable").ToString

    Dim strFilename As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(strFile)


    'Create Directory
    If Not IO.Directory.Exists("D:\Archive\" & strFilename.Substring(0, 4)) Then
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\Archive\" & strFilename.Substring(0, 4))
    End If

    'Copy File to destination
    IO.File.Copy(strFile, "D:\Archive\" & strFilename.Substring(0, 4) & "\" & strFilename)

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

**Second Method - Using File System Task**

Create a new Variable `@[User::DestinationPath]` and set it's property `Evaluate As Expression` = True, then use the following expression for it:

```
"D:\\Archive\\" + LEFT(RIGHT( @[User::Variable] , FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::Variable] ) , "\\", 1) - 1),4)
```

*Variable Screenshot*

[image]

*File System Task*

[image]

Comment: Hi,Thankyou so much, i used the scripting task method but I'm getting a runtime error

Comment: Check that you wrote the variable name correctlu, also note that it is case sensitive