# How to declare a C# variable that returns a sliced string of another variable in my SSIS package?

Tags: c#, ssis, etl

I'm creating a file transfer package that copies files into an output folder and then copies them into a separate archive.  The files are frequently replaced with new files with a file name format such as xxxx20190427.zip I created a foreach loop in SSIS to copy / move the files but I can't figure out how to replace old versions. As I move the files into the output folder, I want to replace the file from the previous load. I'm trying to create a script task that creates a variable based on the substring of the variable declared in the foreach loop so that if the file xxxx20190427.zip is present, it checks for the "xxxx" portion in the filenames of my output folder and deletes that file if it's present so that only the newest file is available.

Comment: The following will get you all files in the requested format: Directory.GetFiles("your folder path", "xxxx*.zip");

Comment: I think that you are looking for the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591799/ssis-dynamically-moving-files-to-folder-with-matching-substring-name . I didn't marked the question as duplicates since i am not sure if i understood what you are looking for exactly!!

Comment: What reason do you have for building this in SSIS?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it's going to be running as a step in my SSIS ETL package.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're after but I do know that there are a bunch of proven standard data ingestion patterns that have been implemented and proven many times. Reading your explanation it sounds like you might have a complicated solution to what is really a simple pattern.If you could explain "big picture" what you are trying to do it will give context. If you could also add clear examples about your problem at hand, it's easier to understand than a large literary explanation

Comment: Addressing your specific question: to turn `xxxx20190427.zip` into `xxx` requires the left function, but I can't provide more hints until you provide more detail. Is xxx always the same length or is it variable? What have you tried so far? What does your code currently look like?

Comment: xxxx is variable so I can't necessarily use left.  The date and file extension is always the same length so I was thinking about using negative values in a substring command.

Comment: I don't do a lot o C# but the easiest way to do this might be to reverse the string, use left, then reverse it back. Unless you can get substring to support what you want. I don't think it takes negative values but please try!

Answer (score 0):

An overview of the process is below, with a couple C# Script Tasks used in this example.  For the Script Tasks be sure to add the proper references as indicated below, with these being the `using` statements at the beginning of each section of code.

- Add an Execute SQL Task to the beginning of the Control Flow.  The file names from the current execution will be held in a table that will be created in this task.  Example SQL for this is below.  This checks if the table exists, drops the table if it's present, and then creates it.
- You probably already have the file name for each iteration stored in a variable, but if not add a string variable at Index 0 of the Foreach Loop.  This can be done on the Variable Mappings pane.
- Within the Foreach Loop add a Script Task after all the components.  Add the string variable holding the file name in the `ReadOnlyVariables` field.  This script task (uses C#) will insert the file name used in each iteration to a table that will be used later.  While doing the insert with C# is a slightly more involved than just an Execute SQL Task, the `FileInfo.Name` property can be used to ensure only the file name is stored, as opposed to the file name with path.
- After the Foreach Loop create another Script Task.  If variables are used to hold the name of the output folder and file prefix add these in the `ReadOnlyVariables` field as before.  Code for this is also below.  First the names of the files from the current execution are retrieved and stored in the `currentExecutionFiles` list.  The files in the output directory are then enumerated through, with any files that have the prefix and were not used in the current package execution deleted.
- This is optional, but I'd recommend adding another Execute SQL Task at the end of the package to drop the table holding the file names.  The `DROP` statement from the first Execute SQL Task can just be used for this.

**CREATE and DROP DDL for Execute SQL Task:**

```
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'DATABASE.SCHEMA.FILES') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
DROP TABLE DATABASE.SCHEMA.FILES 
END;

CREATE TABLE DATABASE.SCHEMA.FILES
(
[FILENAME] VARCHAR(250)
)
```

**C# Script Task to Store File Names:**

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;


string currentFile = Dts.Variables["User::FileNameVariable"].Value.ToString();
FileInfo currentFileInfo = new FileInfo(currentFile);
//Integrated Security for Windows authentication
string connectionStr = @"Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
string cmd = @"INSERT INTO DATABASE.SCHEMA.FILES ([FILENAME]) VALUES (@file)";

 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
 {
     using (SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn))
     {
         SqlParameter pFileName = new SqlParameter("@file", SqlDbType.VarChar);
         pFileName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
         pFileName.Size = 250;
         //use FileInfo.Name to get only file path
         pFileName.Value = currentFileInfo.Name;
         sql.Parameters.Add(pFileName);
         conn.Open();
         //insert file name
         sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
 }
```

**C# Script Task to Delete Old Files:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;


string outputFolder = Dts.Variables["User::OutputFolder"].Value.ToString();
string filePrefix = Dts.Variables["User::FilePrefix"].Value.ToString();

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(outputFolder);
List<string> currentExecutionFiles = new List<string>();

string connectionStr = @"Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
string cmd = @"SELECT [FILENAME] FROM DATABASE.SCHEMA.FILES";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
{
    using (SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader dr = sql.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //get file names from table holding names from current execution
                    currentExecutionFiles.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                }               
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach (FileInfo fi in di.EnumerateFiles())
{
    //check for file with prefix (case insensitive) that was not in current execution
    if (fi.Name.StartsWith(filePrefix, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                        && !currentExecutionFiles.Contains(fi.Name))
    {
        fi.Delete();
    }
}
```